# Trying to select a distinct set of values but exclude some

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function, array-formulas

I have an Excel column that contains names of fruits and from this list I want to only extract the unique set of values into another Worksheet. However to complicate it there are some known values I do not wish to be included. Example:

```
Column H
    Orange
    Apple
    Melon
    Orange
    Lemon
    Lemon
    Lemon
    Raspberry
    Kiwi             - I want this to be excluded.
```

From the above list I want to exclude `Kiwi` so my final list would be:

```
Column C
    Orange
    Apple
    Melon
    Lemon
    Raspberry
```

I am using Excel 2007, VBA can be used if necessary but preference is normal/array formula. I have found some array formula that could give me a distinct list but not sure how to extend it to exclude `Kiwi`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Fruit'!$H$2:$H$100, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C1, 'Fruit'!$H$2:$H$100), 0)),"")
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Fruit!$H$2:$H$100, MATCH(0,IF(Fruit!$H$2:$H$100<>"Kiwi",COUNTIF($C$1:C1, Fruit!$H$2:$H$100)), 0)),"")}
```